# run a particular command on all remote servers as a particular user?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to run a specific Ansible task as a different user than the one who is running the playbook. On my local box I have below playbook and I am logged in as `david` user and I want to run this command `/tek/ghy/bin/ss.sh start` on all remote servers as `goldy` user only.

My .yml file looks like this:

```
---
- name: start server
  hosts: one_box
  serial: "{{ num_serial }}"
  tasks:
      - name: start server
        command: /tek/ghy/bin/ss.sh start
        become: true
        become_user: goldy
```

Below is how I am running it:

```
david@machineA:~$ ansible-playbook -e 'host_key_checking=False' -e 'num_serial=1' start_box.yml -u david --ask-pass --sudo -U goldy --ask-become-pass
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: The sudo command line option has been deprecated in favor of the "become" command line arguments. This feature will be removed in version 2.6. Deprecation warnings
can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
SSH password:
SUDO password[defaults to SSH password]:

PLAY [start server] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [remote_machineA]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Failed to set permissions on the temporary files Ansible needs to create when becoming an unprivileged user (rc: 1, err: chown: changing ownership of ‘/tmp/ansible-tmp-1527357815.74-165519966271795/’: Operation not permitted\nchown: changing ownership of ‘/tmp/ansible-tmp-1527357815.74-165519966271795/setup.py’: Operation not permitted\n}). For information on working around this, see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#becoming-an-unprivileged-user"}
```

What wrong I am doing here? I am running ansible 2.4.3.0

Comment: "*What wrong I am doing here?*" ー you are posting an error to StackOverflow without reading it.

Comment: I have already read the error but doesnt understand what this means `Failed to set permissions on the temporary files Ansible needs to create when becoming an unprivileged user` and how should I fix it?

Comment: You need to read to the very end, maybe you'll find a link to detailed explanation there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by google search, you could be affected by this [issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/31125).

try to upgrade ansible, your code (i replaced the `command` to run a simple `id` on the remote server, instead of the `/tek/ghy/bin/ss.sh start`, and i used the same shell command and arguments as you provided) works on 2.5.2:

```
[ilias@optima-ansible tmp]$ ansible-playbook -e 'host_key_checking=False' -e 'num_serial=1' lala.yml -u ilias --ask-pass --sudo -U http_offline --ask-become-pass 
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: The sudo command line option has been deprecated in favor of the "become" command line arguments. This feature will be removed in version 2.6. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by 
setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
SSH password: 
SUDO password[defaults to SSH password]: 

PLAY [start server] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [greenhat]

TASK [start server] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [greenhat]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [greenhat] => {
    "command_output": {
        "changed": true, 
        "cmd": [
            "id"
        ], 
        "delta": "0:00:00.004484", 
        "end": "2018-05-26 21:26:28.531838", 
        "failed": false, 
        "rc": 0, 
        "start": "2018-05-26 21:26:28.527354", 
        "stderr": "", 
        "stderr_lines": [], 
        "stdout": "uid=1002(http_offline) gid=1002(http_offline) groups=1002(http_offline),984(docker)", 
        "stdout_lines": [
            "uid=1002(http_offline) gid=1002(http_offline) groups=1002(http_offline),984(docker)"
        ]
    }
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
greenhat                   : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0   

[ilias@optima-ansible tmp]$ ansible --version
ansible 2.5.2
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/ilias/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.15 (default, May 16 2018, 17:50:09) [GCC 8.1.1 20180502 (Red Hat 8.1.1-1)]
[ilias@optima-ansible tmp]$
```